# Why doesn't the in operator work with the list of strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, list, arraylist, javascript-objects, issue-tracking

```
let checkExistance = "a" in ["a","b","c","e"];

console.log(checkExistance)// returns false

// wh`your text`y
```

/*I tried the in operator in JavaScript to create a function that takes two parameters an object and property to be removed. I used the in operator to check if the item or property I want to remove exists or not. But the in operator behaves diffently.*/

Comment: For arrays, you should use [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if it contains your value.